# Construction of a field with roots of unity in MAGMA

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, computer-algebra-systems, cyclotomic-polynomials, magma-cas

I would like to construct a field (NumberField) that contains a (primitive) $n$-th root of unity and $i = \sqrt{-1}$ using a computer algebra system [MAGMA](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/), i.e. $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n, i)$.

I tried constructing it as follows (for $n=7$):

```
n := 7;
Qx<x> := PolynomialRing(Rationals());
f := CyclotomicPolynomial(n);
g := x^2+1;
F<a> := SplittingField([f,g])
DefiningPolynomial(F);
```

Here the element `a` gives me the $n$-th root of unity. But how do I get `b` such that $b^2=-1$?

Thanks in advance!
-- Mike

P.S.
If someone wants to test MAGMA, you can try online [here](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/).

Comment: You can create `E<a> := SplittingField(f);` and then `F<i> := SplittingField(g,F);`

Comment: You can also create `F` as a cyclotomic field, `F<a> := CyclotomicField(LCM(n,4));` and then ask for `RootOfUnity(4,F);`

Comment: @MorganRodgers Thanks. I couldnt think of `LCM` command. Also I didnt know how to compute `SplittingField` over another field.